# How to get VM names under backend address pools of load balancer of resource group in azure

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I have tried below command,to get vmname and backend pool name to excel sheet. but its showing only VMs  but not  backend pool name.

[image]
while read rgName
do
vmlist=$(az vm list -g $rgName --query [].name -o tsv)

```
for vm in $vmlist
do
nicId=$(az vm show -g $rgName -n $vm --query networkProfile.networkInterfaces[].id -o tsv)

backendPoolId=$(az network nic show --ids $nicId --query ipConfigurations[].loadBalancerBackendAddressPools[].id -o tsv)

backendPoolName=${backendPoolId##*/}

done

echo $vmlist,$backendPoolName >> test.csv

done < ilb_group
```

Comment: Is there a vmss or vm or vnet as the target in the backend address pool?

Comment: @NancyXiong Vms

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the VMs and backendPoolName, you could use the following bash scripts.

```
#!/bin/bash

rgName=nancylbrg 
vmlist=$(az vm list -g $rgName --query [].name -o tsv)

for vm in $vmlist
do
nicId=$(az vm show -g $rgName -n $vm --query networkProfile.networkInterfaces[].id -o tsv)

backendPoolId=$(az network nic show --ids $nicId --query ipConfigurations[].loadBalancerBackendAddressPools[].id -o tsv)

backendPoolName=${backendPoolId##*/}

done

echo $vmlist,$backendPoolName
```

Result

[image]

[image]

Comment: Getting just VMs but not backend pools, I have echo in to csv file
"echo $vmlist,$backendpoolName >> test.csv"

Comment: Could you show your full commands? It works fine on my side.

Comment: At the first line in your command, change to `while read rgName`, this also works on my side. If the VMs have not targeted to the backend pools, then it will not display the backend pool name.  Do you have multiple VMs instead of VM scale sets in the backend pool? You can see my backend pool.

Comment: each backend pool have two VMs associated.

Comment: If you run the `az network nic show` for one nic, it will get backendPoolId?

Comment: I haven't print backendpoolID

Comment: my requirement is to get backendpools and VMs under the pools which are associated to pool respectively

Comment: I see, but in the `az network lb address-pool list`, it just only displays the nic ipconfig not the VMs. When you add the VMs in the pool, it actually adds the NICs to the backend pool. If one nic has targeted to the backend pool. You should get the backend pool Id.

Comment: shall I print $bakcendpooId and check ?

Comment: Yes, you also could run the command with one specific VM to check it first instead of loop.

Comment: Instead of getting VMs, Getting Nics which are associated to pools also works for me

Comment: If you get the NICs and associated pools, you should also get the pool name from backend pool id with `backendPoolName=${backendPoolId##*/}`?

Comment: AM getting for only bakcend pool. Its not giving rest of the pools

Comment: What do you mean? I remember that you just want to get VMs name and backend pool name from your original question?

Comment: yeah I still need to get backend pool name of all backend pools available

Comment: I am confusing why you did not get the expected result with the same commands. Could you show your screenshots about backend pools configuration in a load balancer?

Comment: Added picture to my question